# Extended Schedule Task in Sitecore not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore8

I have created an extended scheduled task with some parameters and has also added Schedule "20160201T235900|20190201T235900|127|00:10:00" to run every 10 minutes.
Frequncy in web.config is also set to 5 minutes. 00:05:00

But It is not at all executing  somehow. Can anyone help me out with some possible reasons for this.

[Extended Schedule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxHK7.jpg)
|||||[Task Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMvaE.jpg)

Comment: Can you explain "Extended Schedule?" You don't bychance mean the Extended Schedule template that's included when you install Active Commerce for Sitecore?

Comment: Hi @techphoria414 : Thanks for your reply . I have attached two images that show Extended Schedule . I want to schedule that task to run every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This *Extended Schedule* template ships with Active Commerce, and is helpful for specifying parameters that are commonly needed when executing Active Commerce tasks, including a site/shop context, database context, and other parameters.

Out of the box however, the Sitecore `DatabaseAgent` will not execute schedules for items which don't explicitly use Sitecore's Schedule template (even if the template inherits from it, as *Extended Schedule* does).

To work around this, Active Commerce ships with its own extended `DatabaseAgent`. You can enable it by enabling the `xActiveCommerce.Scheduling.config.example` config patch that ships with Active Commerce. In case this example config is missing, I've included its contents below.

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
    <sitecore>
        <scheduling>
            <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent">
                <patch:delete />
            </agent>
            <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent">
                <patch:delete />
            </agent>
            <agent type="ActiveCommerce.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:10:00" instance="master">
                <param desc="database">master</param>
                <param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules</param>
                <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
            </agent>
            <agent type="ActiveCommerce.Tasks.DatabaseAgent" method="Run" interval="00:10:00" instance="core">
                <param desc="database">core</param>
                <param desc="schedule root">/sitecore/system/tasks/schedules</param>
                <LogActivity>true</LogActivity>
            </agent>
        </scheduling>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using InitializeSpeedBooster.config? then you have to delete the following lines:

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeScheduler, Sitecore.Kernel">
   <patch:delete />
</processor>
```